Match pattern for function with variable number of arguments that follow another pattern
I have a set of patterns of the form
nc[]

nc[a[CR,k]]

nc[a[CR,l],a[AN,j]]

nc[a[AN,k],a[CR,j],a[AN,l]]

...

(* and so on *)

The outer function is always nc[] and the inner functions are always a[]. The outer function nc[] can take any number of arguments of the form a[x,y]. The inner functions a[] always take two arguments wich can be anything.
How do I write the pattern which match any of these expressions? I need to use this pattern in tandem with Collect[].

_nc should catch all of these. But I think there is more to it. So please elaborate and provide test cases.

Actually, yes, _nc works. I don't know why I didn't see that one, I'm really just getting the hang of the pattern matching functions.

The following patter will do:
 nc[a[_, _] ...]

For a test, I take a list of all your examples:
t = {nc[],
   nc[a[CR, k]],
   nc[a[CR, l], a[AN, j]],
   nc[a[AN, k], a[CR, j], a[AN, l]]};

t /. nc[a[_, _] ...] -> replaced

{replaced, replaced, replaced, replaced}

